# Apply delete-orphan cascade for pending objects recursively

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, when adding new objects to relationship with default cascades and then deleting them, they are kept inside session and then inserted on flush. But when having delete-orphan cascade, the desired behavior is to remove relative object from session as it is removed from relationship collection.

```py
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key = True)
    section_id = Column(ForeignKey('section.id'))

class Section(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'section'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key = True)
    items = relationship(
        Item,
        cascade = 'save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan'
    )

section = session.get(Section, 1)
item = Item()
section.items.append(item)
section.items.remove(item)
session.flush()
```

So, if `items` have a delete-orphan cascade, then `item` will not be inserted, else it will be. Everything works here. But also everything breaks, if I add another relation, now for `Item` class.

```py
class Part(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'part'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key = True)
    item_id = Column(ForeignKey('item.id'))

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key = True)
    section_id = Column(ForeignKey('section.id'))
    parts = relationship(
        Part,
        cascade = 'save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan'
    )

section = session.get(Section, 1)
part = Part()
item = Item(parts = [part])
section.items.append(item)
section.items.remove(item)

item in session # False, everything's correct
part in session # True, WTF???
session.flush() # And then `part` is inserted with NULL `item_id` value
```

I think something's wrong here, especially I think that this is SQLAlchemy's bug. But maybe some workaround can be performed by now, without manual deletion objects from session?

(I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.4 with psycopg2 and PosgreSQL 14.)

Comment: @python_user Tried. Nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When "delete-orphan" applies to persisted objects, it's causes expunge operation on them. So the solution is to add an "expunge" cascade to all relationships except direct. It is only `Item.parts` in example.

```py
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key = True)
    section_id = Column(ForeignKey('section.id'))
    parts = relationship(
        Part,
        cascade = 'save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan, expunge'
    )
```

Also, I've already posted [an issue in SQLAlchemy repository](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/9348). That behavior has been considered as bug and seems like gonna be fixed in next versions.